# Is it possible to schedule gitlab pipeline in less than an hour?

Tags: cron, gitlab, pipeline

I try to set up a scheduled pipeline that runs every 20 mins. I use the customized cron syntax (`*/20 * * * *`) in the setting, but gitlab doesn't honor this and still runs it every hour.

Is this a gitlab bug or did I miss something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [GitLab schedules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html): it does mention:

> The pipelines won't be executed precisely, because schedules are handled by Sidekiq, which runs according to its interval.
>
> For example, if you set a schedule to create a pipeline every minute (`* * * * *`) and the Sidekiq worker runs on 00:00 and 12:00 every day (`0 */12 * * *`), only 2 pipelines will be created per day.
>
> To change the Sidekiq worker's frequency, you have to edit the **`pipeline_schedule_worker_cron`** value in your `gitlab.rb` and restart GitLab.

Comment: Thanks! That works and my last step is `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` instead of `restart` as I'm using the omnibus version.

Comment: I have the same issue but I am using a hosted free Gitlab version. Is there any workaround for running a pipeline every 15 mins?

Comment: @AnshulTripathi The pipeline schedule page I mention (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html) should be available for a hosted free GitLab version though.

Comment: It says "The pipelines won’t be executed exactly on schedule because schedules are handled by Sidekiq, which runs according to its interval." Since mine is a hosted one so I don't have access to the Gitlab server. I want the pipeline to run every 15 mins. If it is not possible, I would have to change the whole logic which is a bummer.

Answer (score 5):

New way for 12.8.X

To change the Sidekiq worker’s frequency:
Edit the **gitlab_rails['pipeline_schedule_worker_cron']** value in your instance’s **gitlab.rb** file.
The exact line I have checked from gitlab.rb file is

```
# gitlab_rails['pipeline_schedule_worker_cron'] = "19 * * * *"
```

So uncomment the line and for example to run every minute do this.

```
gitlab_rails['pipeline_schedule_worker_cron'] = "* * * * *"
```

Reconfigure GitLab for the changes to take effect.
Then go to job and add this in your job schedule, in this example it will run every 5 minutes :

```
*/5 * * * *
```

Older version 10.x.x the good way is.
Edit the **gitlab_ci['schedule_builds_minute'] = "0"** value in your instance’s **gitlab.rb** file.

Please check the the official page, it's changing offen
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html#advanced-configuration

Comment: Strange, considering this particular setting `schedule_builds_minute` was documented in https://github.com/gitlabhq/omnibus-gitlab/commit/bbbb5001dda1713deb24fed717117434737ccbff, in 2014. Do you have a merge request which documents the new method?

Comment: @VonC, my bad, I have installed in my lab the last version **gitlab-ce-12.8.1-ce** and the documentation is correct, But for my current version **gitlab-ce-12.6.4-ce** there is not **gitlab_rails['pipeline_schedule_worker_cron']** in gitlab.rb,

Comment: @VonC I think It's because the gitlab.rb file has not be changed when I have done the update from 10.2.x to 12.6.4. Strange issue.